# Silent autoupdate running Android application

Tags: android, api, google-play, google-play-services, auto-update

From what I read on SO, it seems that I want the impossible (?)

I have a kiosk-like app that is supposed to run 24/24, 7/7, 365/365. This makes it hard/impossible to update the app. As far as I know, Google Play will not start the update (even if Autoupdate is set for my app) while my app is running.

I read across SO and several forums an found a lot of NO's and CON's. My current answer is that is not possible without rooting the device or without some system certificates and so on.

But still, I have the following scenario:

1. I created a google account myGoogleAccount@gmail.com
2. On my device I add this account and install my application from Google Play store.
3. On my desktop machine I log into GPlay with the same account and I go to my application and I see that my app is Installed. If I click on the Installed button I can see my device.
4. I publish a new version of the app, when the app becomes available, from my application's page open on desktop I can send a command to update the app.
   I get the prompt to accept the terms bla-bla, and once I accept it, the app is automatically updated even if it is currently running.

Basically this is the behavior I am interested in. My question is: can I run this scenario from my device [invoking some GPlay api's] given the fact that I can provide the google account credentials to the app, so that no user intervention is required to update the app and to accept whatever unchanged permissions?

Comment: Even if you make working scenario with autoupdate of running app, you will should restart application after update - without it new package resources & code will not start and in memory will run still old version of your app.

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html?hl=en)? What have you tried?

Comment: @Dimmerg This is already solved, my app restarts after package install (see android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED)

Comment: @t0mm13b good resource, let me study it...

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem and still haven't found a solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769137/auto-update-of-an-android-app-never-happens). I'm now thinking maybe I have to quit the app for a few minutes to give the update a chance to come through?