# Auto-update of an Android app never happens

Tags: android

I have a somewhat unusual Android app in the Play Store that's running on dedicated devices 24/7 (it collects sensor data, it's not meant to run on phones used for anything else). I would like the app to auto-update without user interaction, but that never seems to happen. Why could this be?

Some more background:

- Auto-update is explicitly turned on for the app on the devices.
- Other apps do seem to auto-update.
- The app stops and restarts itself every 12 hours; mostly to whack the app out of any weird state it might get into and clear memory, but I was also hoping this would give it a chance to auto-update. There is a 10 second delay until the app restarts.
- The devices are mostly old phones (HTC Desire C) running Android 4.0.4

This is fairly hard and time-consuming to test so any experiences shared with similar requirements could be helpful.

Comment: Didn't you find any solution or more info on this?

Comment: No, we were never able to resolve this. Best theory I have is that for some reason the app was blacklisted for automatic updates?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the port 5228, TCP and UDP, is not blocked by a firewall per https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2651367?hl=en

We've had a similar problem for years. Our apps run on school deployed devices. Whenever we push an update, it reaches may be 10% of devices within 24 hours, the rest seem to "hang". It takes about a week for another 30% of devices to get the update, while the remaining %60 never get it. There is no difference in settings across devices. All set to auto-update of course.

The way we "solved it" is our app is checking if the market has a newer version (there are libraries for doing it, but we have own server responding yes/no). If there is a newer version of the app, we invoke the intent to open Google Play with the app's page. The user has to manually click "Update" at that point.

If there was a native or cleaner way to push the updates we'd love to hear, even at this point in the game. Bothering users to update is not ideal.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same thing now and I would like to hear if you found something better since last time.

Comment: Not at all. The auto-updates are not reliably delivered.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot: Maybe there was any change in the apps required permissions?

That would require manual updating (even if auto-update is on). Maybe you installed the app first in those old devices, then changed the permissions, then installed the app in new devices, then updated the app. That would make the autoupdate system work in the newer devices, and not work in the older ones.

Comment: Not a bad call, but the permissions haven't changed in a while and certainly not since the version the devices I would like to update are running.