# Auto-update for headless Android application

Tags: android, auto-update

We're developing a headless Android application that will run on dedicated devices. It requires automatic updates without user involvement when there is a fix or improvement available. But this is the problematic part. I researched and found many suggestions but none of them is the exact solution.

- When we let the application get the latest apk and initiate update itself,
  it requires confirmation from user at the final step, unless system
  is rooted.

  - Rooting the system for all devices may not be practical.
- When it's deployed through PlayStore, automatic update may not be happened for all devices. Even if automatic update setting is enabled in the device's Google PlayStore, automatic update may be late for days or weeks, or may not happen at all. This issue is mentioned here: [Auto-update of an Android app never happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769137/auto-update-of-an-android-app-never-happens)
- I found this tool: [Evolve](https://github.com/VivekPanyam/Evolve). It tricks the system in some way so update without user involvement becomes possible. But the only commit on the github was "initial commit" 3 years ago. Also in [here](https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users/), it says:

> Evolve is in Alpha. This means that it probably won't work without some debugging. Please find issues and submit pull requests!

So what would you propose? How can it be possible? Am I missing something? Any comment or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Ask the device manufacturer. After all, the device manufacturer is supplying you with the devices and with their custom ROM. Your app is being pre-installed on those devices. The device manufacturer will have instructions for how to update your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare it might help to some extent. But different devices may be in the game, that's also why I said "Rooting the system for all devices may not be practical." So I'm looking for more generic solutions.

Comment: There is no "generic solution". Evolve and similar approaches are not replacing the APK. They are more for "hot fixes" of code, and securing that sort of code change is very difficult. And, because they cannot replace the APK, they cannot change things in the manifest. Personally, I do not recommend these solutions. "Different devices" is not a viable option for your scenario, IMHO.